# vim , reformat text for programming

Tags: vim

I've a big file with lines that look like

> 2 No route to specified transit
>   network
>
> 3 No route to destination

And I'd like to transform that for use in a programming language to

> {2,"No route to specified transit
>   network"},
>
> {3,"No route to destination"},

How would I do this ?

Comment: Do all of the lines begin with a number, followed by a space?

Comment: You ask this question on StackOverflow too. That's not very cool for the Google ranking (duplicate contents) of the answer if someone has the same question later... ;-)

Comment: Link to the question on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366682/vim-reformat-text-to-initializers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic conversion is,

```
sed 's|^\([0-9]\)\(.*\)|{\1,"\2"}|g' file.txt > file2.txt
```

in `vim`,

```
:%s/\([0-9] \(.*\)/{\1,"\2"}/g
```

This will cover lines starting with the format,

```
N text on the line...
```

Where `N` is a single digit number.
Can be extended further for other forms.

Answer (score 4):

In your case, a simple regular expression is enough (and the best solution). However, in some other cases, recording a **macro** might be better.

There is a simple macro example at [vim documentation, section 12.1](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_12.html#12.1), and further description at `:help q`

In a nutshell:

1. Type `q` followed by a letter (the letter is the `register` where the macro will be recorded).
2. Do some commands, modify your text as needed, use all power of Vim.
3. Move the cursor to the next line.
4. Press `q` to stop recording.

To play a macro, press `@` followed by the letter where the macro was recorded. To re-play the last macro, press `@@`. Type a number before playing a macro to repeat it as many times as needed.

So, in your case, to transform the lines like this:

```
2 No route to specified transit network
{2, "No route to specified transit network"},
```

1. Position your cursor at one of the lines.
2. Press `qa` (the choice of register `a` was arbitrary).
3. Press exactly this (including quotes and spaces) `I{<esc>f cl, "<esc>A"},<esc>j`
4. Press `q` to stop recording.
5. Press `100@a` and be happy watching the macro being played. :-)

I'll leave to the reader the explanation of each command from step 3. ;-)

Of course, this is not the only solution. You could have done the step 3 in many different ways.

Answer (score 1):

Does this vim command do what you want ?

```
%s/^\(.\)\ \(.*\)$/{\1,\ "\2"},/g
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/^\s*\(\d\+\)\s\+\(\S.\{-}\)\s*$/{\1, "\2"}/
```